# JS clear timer of previous function call before new function call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, timer, slider, cleartimeout

My React app uses a slider component from Material UI. Its onChange event calls a function to update the state. I realized that my component rerenders for every slider step which is why I want to delay the updating of the state for like 300ms after the last time the slider was moved.

My approach is to start a timer with the state update via onChange. When the onChange is called again, the previous timer should be canceled though. This is the part I still struggle with.

The setSliderValue is a function which takes a number to update the state. **How do I clear "timer"  only when sliderChangeHandler is called again?**

```
const [sliderValue, setSliderValue] = useState(20);

const sliderChangeHandler = (event, newValue) => {
    const timer = setTimeout(setSliderValue, 300, newValue);
    clearTimeout(timer);
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set `setTimeout` return value in your state:

```js
const [sliderValue, setSliderValue] = useState(20);
const [timer, setTimer] = useState();

const sliderChangeHandler = (event, newValue) => {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    const newTimer = setTimeout(setSliderValue, 300, newValue);
    setTimer(newTimer);
};
```

I would suggest to you to use this lib for debouncing any function: https://github.com/xnimorz/use-debounce

In your case it would be:

```js
const [sliderValue, setSliderValue] = useState(20);

const debounced = useDebouncedCallback(
  // function
  setSliderValue,
  // delay in ms
  300,
);

// some part of the code
debounced.callback(30);
```

In this case every time you call `debounced.callback` it will cancel previous call

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I prefer the vanilla JS/React way (your first solution) :)

Comment: Nice, glad it helped. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I use a `useRef` hook usually for debounce. Something like:

```
const timeoutRef = useRef(null)

const [sliderValue, setSliderValue] = useState(20)

const onChange = (e, v) => {
  clearTimeout(timeoutRef.current)
  timeoutRef.current = setTimeout(setSliderValue, 300, v)
}
```

Saves a line of code ;)